# Javascript split url on filters

Tags: javascript

Im giving my users the possibility to filter products without refreshing the page with ajax. i update the url to make it look like :

http://mywebsite.com/products/filter?style=7-1-2&price=4-5-7&brand=48-12-5&color=8-4

where the int values are id's split by -.
so i have the options:

style

price

brand

color

what i want is get these values in a var for each filter option so that i end with :

```
var styleValues = 7,1,2
var priceValues = 4,5,7
```

if only price filter is selected the url will look like

http://mywebsite.com/products/filter?price=4-5-7

so i cant split on the tags for the filters.

I really like to know what would be the best way to turn the url to different vars.

**What i already know :**

how to get the filter part:

```
var filterPart =window.location.search;
```

Comment: @DavidThomas typo ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great article on css tricks covering just this: 
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-and-url-parts-in-javascript/
JavaScript can access the current URL in parts. For this URL:

http://css-tricks.com/example/index.html

window.location.protocol = "http:"
window.location.host = "css-tricks.com"
window.location.pathname = "example/index.html"
So to get the full URL path in JavaScript:

```
var newURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + window.location.pathname;
```

If you need to breath up the pathname, for example a URL like http://css-tricks.com/blah/blah/blah/index.html, you can split the string on "/" characters

```
var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
```

Then access the different parts by the parts of the array, like

```
var secondLevelLocation = pathArray[0];
```

To put that pathname back together, you can stitch together the array and put the "/"'s back in:

```
var newPathname = "";
for (i = 0; i < pathArray.length; i++) {
  newPathname += "/";
  newPathname += pathArray[i];
}
```

Or like this::

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/

```
function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help you :

```
var Request = {
QueryString : function (item) {
    var svalue = location.search.match(new RegExp("[\?\&]" + item + "=([^\&]*)(\&?)","i"));
    return svalue?svalue[1]:svalue;
},

queryAllString : function() {
    var urlLocation = location.href;
    var startPosition = urlLocation.indexOf("?");
    if (startPosition < 0) {
        return '';
    } else {
        return urlLocation.slice(startPosition);
    }
}
}
```

If you want to get price,you can do like this:

```
Request.QueryString("price")
```

Answer (score 0):

My own take on this problem would be:

```js
// this is simply to compensate for the lack of a current document.location to search:
var documentURL = 'http://mywebsite.com/products/filter?style=7-1-2&price=4-5-7&brand=48-12-5&color=8-4',
  tempA = document.createElement('a');
tempA.href = documentURL

var searches = {
  'get': function() {
    var queries = {
        // a cache of all named parameters found:
        'found': []
      },
      // stripping off the leading '?':
      queryString = tempA.search.substring(1),
      // getting the key-value pairs:
      keyValues = queryString.split('&'),
      // to be used withi the forEach():
      pair;
    keyValues.forEach(function(el) {
      // creating an array consisting of the keyName and keyValue:
      pair = el.split('=');
      // if we have both a name and a value we proceed:
      if (pair.length === 2) {
        if (!queries[pair[0]]) {
          // if there is no present entry for the current key, we:
          // push the key to the 'found' array, and
          // create a record in the queries object for that key
          // containing an array of the found values:
          queries.found.push(pair[0]);
          queries[pair[0]] = pair[1].split('-');
        } else {
          // otherwise (there is an existing key in the queries object),
          // we push the values to the end of the existing array:
          queries[pair[0]].push(pair[1])
        }
      }
    });
    return queries;
  }
};

var cachedSearches = searches.get(),
    allKeys = cachedSearches.found;

allKeys.forEach(function(el){
  console.log(el, cachedSearches[el], cachedSearches[el].join(', '));
});
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
- [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var filtered = {};
var url = "http://mywebsite.com/products/filter?style=7-1-2&price=4-5-7&brand=48-12-5&color=8-4";
var filters = url.split("?")[1].split("&");
filters.map(function(val) {
  filtered[val.split("=")[0]] = val.split("=")[1].split("-").join(",")
});
console.log(filtered);
```

```js
var filtered = {};
var url = "http://mywebsite.com/products/filter?style=7-1-2&price=4-5-7&brand=48-12-5&color=8-4";
var filters = url.split("?")[1].split("&");
filters.map(function(val, i) { 
  filtered[val.split("=")[0]] = val.split("=")[1].split("-").join(",");
  document.body.innerText += (Object.keys(filtered)[i].toString() +": "+ filtered[val.split("=")[0]]) + "\n"
});
```